# Changing the view color for every 30 seconds with three colors

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm trying to change the background color of UIview for every 30 seconds with three different colors till the condition fail(while loop). Below is my code. It's working fine but, causing delay.

Swift 3:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    while x < y {
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString:hexValue[self.currentColorIndex!])
        }
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 30.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put you app to sleep

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this solution, not perfect, I guess. For 3 colours it would work, for more you should study about `Timer` or create some `for-loop`

```
func changeColor() {
    if x < y {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString:hexValue[0])
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 30, execute: { [weak self] in
            self?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString:hexValue[1])
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 30, execute: { [weak self] in
                self?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString:hexValue[2])
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 30, execute: { [weak self] in
                    self?.changeColor()  
                 })
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: intial color index will not be zero all the time..it changes depending on the app start time

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
    func changeColor(newIndex: Int) {
        func next(_ index: Int) -> Int {
            return Int(Double(index + 1).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: hexValue.count - 1))
        }

        guard x < y else { return }

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: hexValue[newIndex])

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 30) {
            self.changeColor(newIndex: next(newIndex))
        }
    }
```

Please note how you can add/remove as many colors as you'd like from your array without the need to change this code at all :)

On the first call you should call with parameter 0 (or any other color you'd like to start with) `changeColor(newIndex: 0)`

Comment: using DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 30), it's giving an initial delay of 30 seconds and the thread is not being killed to display the next color. it constantly displaying the same color forever.

Comment: my bad, I've forgot to change a line of code (just updated)

Comment: the dispatch is used to call the func again for the second time, the change color will be done immediately when you call the function.

Comment: I actually have to initialize the color index to zero everytime if it reaches 3

Comment: you call the func once and then it does everything by itself (including autoresetting to zero)

Answer (score 0):

this is my actual code:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    while self.loopStartTime! < Int64(ed_time){
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
                            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: hexValue[self.currentColorIndex!])
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: self.loop!)
                        if self.loop != 3.0{
                            self.loopStartTime = self.loopStartTime! + Int64((self.loop!*1000))
                        }
                        else{
                            self.loopStartTime = self.loopStartTime! + addedTime
                        }
                        self.currentColorIndex = self.currentColorIndex! + 1
                        if self.currentColorIndex! >= hexValue.count{
                            self.currentColorIndex = 0
                        }
                        self.loop = 3.0
                    }
}
```